# JavaScript: understanding void 0 in ?? operator polyfill

Tags: javascript, reactjs, null-coalescing-operator

I was curious whether null coalescing operator `??` had a polyfill in default `create-react-app` setup. It turns out it does:

```
const App = () => {
    const foo = 'custom value';

    return (
        <div>
            {foo ?? 'default value'}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Becomes:

```js
const App = () => {
  const foo = 'custom value';
  return /*#__PURE__*/Object(react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["jsxDEV"])("div", {
    children: foo !== null && foo !== void 0 ? foo : 'default value'
  }, void 0, false, {
    fileName: _jsxFileName,
    lineNumber: 7,
    columnNumber: 9
  }, undefined);
};
```

The most interesting part is the `foo !== null && foo !== void 0 ? foo : 'default value'`, which is the polyfill for the `??` operator. While `foo !== null` is obvious, I don't quite get the `foo !== void 0` part. What does it mean?

I checked and `void 0 === undefined` is `true`, but why isn't it simply `foo !== undefined`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`void 0` is the same thing as `undefined`, *most of the time*. There are two benefits to using `void 0`:

- It's shorter (which can be useful for minifiers)
- The identifier `undefined` can be created when not on the top level, leading to unexpected behavior:

```js
(() => {
  const undefined = 'foo';

  // later in the code:

  const actuallyUndef = (() => {})();
  console.log(actuallyUndef === undefined);
})();
```

That's an extremely pathological case, but using `void 0` is a tiny bit safer.

Ancient browsers used to permit the creation of `undefined` on the top level as well, but this is luckily no longer permitted.

Comment: See, I didn't know that you can overwrite `undefined` inside a function! I thought that modern browsers just don't allow it, but you are right! Overwriting `undefined` inside a function actually works, even in strict mode.